# Update jekyll theme in bloggy gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll

Bloggy is a rails gem that allows `/blog` to be created within a rails application. However the default theme is very simple. Is there a way to update the default theme?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Bloggy but I assume everything works like Jekyll, so for a custom template you can edit it yourself :

[Documentation from Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/)

I also found this website with multiple themes:

http://jekyllthemes.org

Here is a [piece of documentation from Jekyll about themes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/)